# Laravel/Vite/Inertiajs - custom page import from Pages/subfolders

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs

I have problem with adjusting code to new "extension necessary" format in app.js

my app.js code:

```
createInertiaApp({
resolve: async name => {
    let page = (await import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`)).default;

    //if page dont have layout - import default one
    if (page.layout == undefined) {
        page.layout = Layout;
    }

    return page;
},
```

This line below in fresh install looks like:

```
resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
```

I've trying to merge both objects:

```
resolve: async name => {
    let page = (await import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`)).default;
    let pageAuth = (await import(`./Pages/Auth/${name}.vue`)).default;

    Object.assign(page, pageAuth);
```

but it search every (root) page also in subfolder so it ends in errors that file not exist or white pages display.

How to upgrade my code to search in subdirectories ?

Im quite beginner in JS.

Other code tries gives error taht dynamic import not support * charracters

my goal is to be able to attach layout to every single page if its not specified (root or subfolder)

Answer (score 1):

I feel so dumb. I resolved it by:

```
resolve: async name => {
    let page = resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue'))
```